# What's the correct way to start up the computer?

Tags: windows-10-preview, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I'm not sure if it's me or if it's Win 10 not being fully sane. When I close the lid on my Surface, it goes into the default sleep mode (it's set not to shut down but just sleep for both lid-closing and power-buttoning independently of whether an external power source is connected or if it's running on batteries). This far it's as supposed to.

However, in the morning, when I open the lid, I'd like it to say "surface" or "hello" or "powering up" or anything at all. The screen is just dark. I can see that the keyboard gets light up and pressing the Win-thingy on the screen part makes it go bzzz so it's definitely up and running.

Usually, I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> a few times, then swipe with my finger on the screen, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd> again and some swipy-swipy. At some occasion I just rebooted the stupid thing just to get into Windows. Some days it does on the first try (one swipe and we've got login screen showing), others it takes several attempts.

I suspect that I'm too impatient and I just need to do **one single thing** and then give the machine some time to get running. So, the question is as follows.

What is the correct, minimal sequence of steps to get my Surface wake up and display the login screen?

Comment: I've experienced the same issue; it's likely just a bug in the current build. Sometimes connecting/disconnecting the charger seems to actually wake it when nothing else will.

Comment: @GrahamWager Is this a comment or a reply? I won't be able to mark it as accepted answer if it's the former.

Comment: I guess I see it more of a workaround than a proper answer, just hope it helps on occasion :) hopefully it'll be fixed next build so this won't be relevant any more; it's been driving me nuts too!